# org.apache.camel.ValidationException: Allowed body types are String or InputStream

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, el, spring-camel

I'm getting type compatibility issue while using EL to parse the request body in JSON. Can some one help me on this ?

```
from("file-watch:test?events=CREATE&useFileHashing=true&antInclude=**/*.csv&recursive=true")
        .routeId("fileWatch")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"File Consumed Name: ${header.CamelFileName}")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"File Path: ${header.CamelFileAbsolute}")
        .to("direct:test")
        .end();


from("direct:test")
        .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("CamelFile"))
        .to("jslt:request.json?contentCache=true")
        .to("log:requestObject?level=INFO&showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
        .end();
```

I have placed `request.json` under `classpath:`

**request.json**

```
{
  "fileName": $headers.CamelFileNameOnly
}
```

**Exception:**

```
ERROR 38583 --- [elFileWatchPoll] route1                                   : org.apache.camel.ValidationException: Allowed body types are String or InputStream.. Exchange[8FA7E549F6D864D-0000000000000000] Exception occurred while processing the file:::bob
```

Comment: Try logging the body-type with `.log("body-type: ${body.getClass().getName()}")` before sending it to jslt endpoint to see if body is of type string or InputStream. If not then you'll probably need to convert it to such.

Comment: @PasiÖsterman: Its returning `boolean` is there a type converter to update/convert the body ?

Comment: Are you expecting the body to be a boolean? If so then you can try `.convertBodyTo(String.class)`

Comment: Haven't used jslt but based on the documentation I would assume that the jslt-endpoint expects the body to be either json-format String or InputStream. If you want to just output something in json you could try marshaling object or map (i.e with camel-jackson), use templates (i.e with camel-velocity) or just set the body to json-string with simple-language.

Comment: @PasiÖsterman: I was able to resolve by converting the body type to String.